# Removing newlines in Postgres dump

Tags: postgresql, import, sed, export

I'm trying to format a postgres dump (pg_dump) to be able to import it using a JDBC connection. pg_dump exports text fields that contain newlines to as just that, text with newlines, so when I later try to import using JDBC I reach the end of line and the statement fails.

What I want to do is take the dump, pass it through `sed` and escape all newlines, so that I end up with one `INSERT` statement per line. Problem is that I cannot just remove all newlines, but I can remove all newlines that **do no  match** this `);\nINSERT INTO`. Is there a simple way to do just this?

**Update**:
A sample would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (123, And here goes some text
with
newlines
in
it', 'some more fields');
```

and the result I'm looking for is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (123, And here goes some text\nwith\nnewlines\nin\nit', 'some more fields');
```

So that each `INSERT`statement is on a single line, with the string's newlines escaped.

Comment: your problem description is very confusing. Can you show sample 'dump', plus what you need as final output (just  line or 2 of before and after). Good luck.

Comment: Just added a sample to show what I'm looking for.

Comment: You'd better change your SQL parser to be able to cope with character literals that span several lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a `sed` solution, but might the following work?

```
cat test_dump.txt | perl -pe "s/[^(\);INSERT INTO)]\n/\\$1\\n/"
```

Comment: this was helpful but this saved me pg_dump --dbname=my_db_name --column-inserts -C  |  perl -pe "{ if (/^INSERT INTO/ and ! /^INSERT INTO.*\);$/) { chomp; }}"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **vim**.

```
vim my_dump.sql

:%s/\();\)\@<!\n\(INSERT\)\@!//c
```

% .. do for all lines
s .. substitute
\n .. newline (Unix style; you are aware, that Windows has `\r\n` and Apple `\r` for line breaks?)

flags:
c .. Confirm each substitution (for testing first)

info on negative lookahead and lookbehind
:help \@!
:help \@<!

---

**sed** normally operates on *lines*, it needs to go out of its way to replace line breaks.
Google for "sed multi-line replace", you'll find stuff like [this](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/).